# Can insulation resistance be properly measured at low voltages such as 20 V?

Tags: resistance, insulation, test-equipment

I'm attempting to better understand the process of measuring insulation resistance. As you will infer, I am not at all familiar with this measurement.

We have a connector prototype that we have designed and would like to test and rate it.

I have a Keithley 2450 SourceMeter (SMU) which claims to be able to do insulation resistance testing. However, the [user guide suggests using 20 volts during setup](https://download.tek.com/manual/2450-900-01E_Aug_2019_User.pdf) (pg 6-10). I am surprised by this because my assumption was that insulation resistance testing is done at higher voltages near the expected rating (e.g. 500 V, 1kV, etc.). Since it can measure extremely low currents, I presume the SMU calculates the resistance despite the low test voltage.

- Is measuring insulation resistance at 20 V with a source measure unit a reliable method? (Or is it intended only for approximation or certain use cases?)
- Is using higher voltage to measure insulation resistance considered a destructive test? I assume that once insulation breakdown begins, the sample being measured should be discarded.

Comment: Please add a link to the user manual and a page reference so we can read the context. Thanks.

Comment: You should read the manual about the measurement ranges of the  insulation resistance and the voltages and currents used for each range. Keithley has built instruments for femtoamperes, so they may measure gigaohm and above using low voltages of about 10 or 20 V. So read the specs.

Comment: `my assumption was that insulation resistance testing is done at higher voltages near the expected rating (e.g. 500 V, 1kV, etc.)` ... that may be for testing insulation breakdown

Comment: Does the manual specify you need to use a really thin piece of insulation for the test????

Comment: @Transistor Added. The instructions are quite vague about measurement capabilities. It has fA and nA capabilities, but I was less concerned with this specific unit and more inquiring about source measure units in general (as opposed to, say, a "Megger" or megaohm-meter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A measurement is never improper; it is not usual, though, for a resistance measurement to be performed on electrical insulation, which ignores the possibility of dielectric breakdown.

Simple Ohm's law resistance is a linear property, and a low voltage test (like, 20V) will measure it well.   At higher voltages, though, insulation may diverge from the linear, the voltage-versus-current may make a corner in
the otherwise straight line.   That corner is called breakdown (it isn't always material damaging, just a
kink in the resistance curve is enough).

For safety purposes, a knowledge of the breakdown character is desired, and high voltages are the usual
test condition employed.   Avalanche charge multiplication occurs, sometimes heating in spots, and
the result can be an electric arc that can set material
afire, or an electrical shock to a person handling an appliance.

For safety, not only is high voltage applied, but a human-body model (perhaps just a resistor) is applied as a load.   Safety regulations apply to most such testing, and
the SMU instructions cannot be a complete guide.

As for discarding after test, mostly testing is done both on machine types (and one test unit is destroyed) but also a high voltage stress test is applied to each unit before shipment.   Such testing is beyond normal working limits, so is NOT to be repeated, even in later servicing of those items.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. This gives me an enhanced overview.

Answer (score 1):

Resistance for "semiconductors" and "insulators" (which are really a similar thing, just from different temperature points of view) is not constant. The current rises exponentially when more voltage is applied.

When you measure a resistance at 20 V to be e.g. 1 TΩ, the resistance at e.g. 200 V will be *lower*.

In addition, high voltages will give rise to breakdown which will reduce resistance even more abruptly.

Therefore, you cannot omit the insulation testing at the full voltage at which the part will be specced.

Comment: I will add higher voltage testing to our method; thanks for the helpful info.